# Running my program in github codespace - bash: basics/05_strings.js: Permission denied

Tags: javascript, string, github, codespaces

bash: basics/05_strings.js: Permission denied

im trying to execute my code in github codespace but its not execute, may be because of exceeding limit of my codespace space, bash is giving me pemission denied message evan i turn on sync to vscode and etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change File permission: chmod +x basics/05_strings.js